# Hooking up Webpack with Node Back-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, server

I've built a well functioning outline for React App that I am running locally. I've uploaded the code to Github here: https://github.com/KingOfCramers/React-App-Boilerplate.

I want to serve this React server up using Node and Express (There's a relevant [tutorial](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0) on freeCodeCamp). I am using Webpack, however, in my front-end, because I don't want to use the `create-react-app` command they recommend.

Instead, I use npm run dev-server to run my server locally. Here's what my React-App Server boilerplate package.json looks like:

[image: I currently boot up my project using npm run dev-server]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do it, but still have questions. The steps, in the order I did them:

1. Add a server folder in the root directory of the project, add to that a server.js file.
2. Create an express server on the server.js file. Set it to use the public path. Here's mine:

   [image]

Here are my scripts in the node app's package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "server": "node server/server.js",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
```

When I run npm run build, I will rebuild my app with Webpack. When I want to deploy it, I can then run npm run server, which runs my node server/serve.js command.

Does this make sense? Will I maintain server-side and client-side routing independently with this setting?

Comment: it makes sense the node server can run independently and the webpack  can too . If you want to clear the mess up just create seperate folder for client and server and also seperate package.json for both . But the this is also correct .